# Triggering a Theme Change Which Raises FrameworkElement.Loaded/Unloaded

Tags: wpf, loaded

According to MSDN, the FrameworkElement events Loaded and Unloaded [can be triggered by user-initiated system theme changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded.aspx). I've experimented with changing various theme, color and sound settings on Windows 7 without seeing either of those WPF events raised.

How do I make a user-initiated system theme change--which triggers the raising of Unloaded and Loaded--happen? (I'm interested for application testing purposes.)

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 1):

With application up and running, go to Control Panel -> Personalization.

Scroll down to 'Basic and High Contrast Themes'.
Switch between Windows 7 Basic and Windows Classic.

This will generate a 'theme changed' event to your application.